# Angular 2 innerHTML is not working with slice or textarea

Tags: angular

I have a string called user.about and this is what it looks like:

```
<p>Sed varius nisl id malesuada rutrum. Praesent sodales mattis rhoncus. Cras in sem a est euismod maxim us nec sed dui. Curabitur id nisl condimentum, sodales mauris eget, tempus felis.</p><p>Aenean in porttitor libero, vitae euismod dolor. Aliquam vel sagittis est, vitae volutpat nulla. Inte ger cursus sagittis erat at rhoncus. Sed blandit feugiat imperdiet. Nunc aliquam ut nunc eget accumsan. Nunc ut nisi eget augue aliquet porta a vitae justo.</p><p>Sed varius nisl id malesuada rutrum. Praesent sodales mattis rhoncus. Cras in sem a est euismod maxim us nec sed dui. Curabitur id nisl condimentum, sodales mauris eget, tempus felis.</p><p>Aenean in porttitor libero, vitae euismod dolor. Aliquam vel sagittis est, vitae volutpat nulla. Inte ger cursus sagittis erat at rhoncus. Sed blandit feugiat imperdiet. Nunc aliquam ut nunc eget accumsan. Nunc ut nisi eget augue aliquet porta a vitae justo.</p>
```

What I am trying to do is use this string in two difference places, but use the paragraph tags, I am trying to use this with slice:

```
<p [innerHTML]="user.about">{{user.about | slice:1:150}}</p>
```

This is not working at all,

I am also trying use innerHTML in a textarea like so:

```
<textarea name="about" [(ngModel)]="user.about" rows="7" class="area2" [innerHTML]="user.about">{{user.about}}</textarea>
```

But this also did not work. Its displaying the paragraph tags when I am expected them not to have the paragraph tags, but to have the spacing of them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because angular is sanitizing content making html tags "a text" so no injections may occure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in an editable area, you need a `contenteditable` element.

For display-only, just use `[innerHTML]` and call `slice` normally (no "template syntax" within these attributes):

```
<h1>Editable area</h1>
<div contenteditable [innerHTML]="user.about"></div>

<h1>Paragraph with slice</h1>
<p [innerHTML]="user.about.slice(0, 150)"></p>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raq9kh)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [innerHtml] or curly braces but not both at the same time, if you remove the curly braces in the text area it should work.

On the other hand if you need to slice the text inside the paragraph tags you may need to assign just the text to a different variable